# Get CSS property from a dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an dynamicly added div that I am calling to my page via a javascript tag added to the bottom from a third party plugin. I want to check if this element has the css value display:none or block.
Im having trouble accessing the elements info I think because it was rendered to the page after my script. is there a way to check for this? i tried this:

```
if($('.element').css('display') == 'none') {
    alert("none");
} else { 
    alert("block");
}
```

Comment: Dynamically added elements should be available just like standard ones. When is your check running, before or after the element is added to the page?

Comment: No there is no errors, and I put my script at the bottom after everything.

Comment: Do you want to see the script that is used to call it to the page, or how it renders after page load?

Comment: Try this: if($('.element').is(':visible')){ alert('Showing') } else{ alert('Not showing') }

Comment: @Ulrik McArdle works, thank you! answer as question ill up vote it if you want.Thanks!